# entering a list as a function's default value in kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin

I defined the function "fireAtTarget" in kotlin. As an argument, I need to insert a default value for the list. How could I achieve this?

```
fun fireAtTarget(massKg: Double=80.2, eachGunAmmo: List<Int>=listOf(2, 3): Boolean{

       //function body

  }
```

I expect to call fireAtTarget() with no arguments getting 0 error messages

Comment: "_How could I achieve this_". By giving the parameter a default value you want? You currently have a default list containing `2` and `3`. What about that doesn't fit your requirements (besides missing a closing parenthesis for the function)?

Comment: @slaw It gives me the error, "Expecting a top level declaration" at the first line and another error "function declaration must have a name" in the function body. As well as  i don't believe

Comment: @AbdullahShehab Then: 1. show the actual code which gives the error; 2. include the complete error message. The only problem with the part you show is, as Slaw says, a missing closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 3):

I was experiencing this problem (IntelliJ reports an error `Expecting a top level declaration`) with the following code:

```kotlin
fun foo(value: List<Int>=listOf(1,2)) { }
```

The problem was solved by inserting whitespace space before the equals `List<Int>*space*=listOf`

```kotlin
fun foo(value: List<Int> = listOf(1,2)) { }
```

The Kotlin language has a `>=` operator that the original may be confused with.

See: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#comparison

Answer (score 2):

You can create a list with default value like this:

```
val defaultValueList = List<String>(10) {"I am default"}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in your code: you simply forgot to close bracket in function parameters declaration:

```
fun fireAtTarget(massKg: Double=80.2, eachGunAmmo: List<Int> = listOf(2,3)): Boolean {
       //function body
}
```